# Can gin framework get json post data like `map[string]interface{}` instead of binding with struct?

Tags: go, go-gin

As title said, I am writing an API taking whatever json data that client posts.
Is there any way directly get a `map[string]interface{}` type data like `bson.M`?

I've tried simply looking up properties of `gin.Context`, is any of them would help if I miss something?

Answer (score 6):

1. Directly get `[]bytes` from body of request
2. Use `json.Unmarshal()` to convert `[]bytes` into JSON like data: `map[string]interface{}`

```golang
func GetJsonData(c *gin.Context) {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(data))

    var jsonData bson.M  // map[string]interface{}
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
    if e := json.Unmarshal(data, &jsonData); e != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"msg": e.Error()})
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, jsonData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use json decoder

```
    type jsonPrametersMap map[string]interface{}
    var m jsonPrametersMap

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(c.Request.Body))

    if err := decoder.Decode(&m); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

playground [here](https://go.dev/play/p/YGxNoQW4fGs)